# What is the usefulness of adding a colon ":" to arguments in the declaration of a function?

Tags: functions, function-construction, arguments

I'm studying a code with the following function declaration :

FindChain[ x:__ ,y_?FindChainQ,z:__] := { {x},y,{z} }

**What is  the meaning of the colon ":" after the arguments x and z ?**

**What would be the diference(s) with this declaration (without the colons) :**

FindChain[ x__,y_?FindChainQ,z__] := { {x},y,{z} }

Thank you,

Comment: Check the documentation of `SetDelayed`.

Comment: Check the documentation for [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html) too. It says: _The form `s_` is equivalent to `s:_` Similarly ... `s__` to `s:__`_. You can see this by doing `FullForm[s__]` and `FullForm[s : __]` . The purpose of it is a shorthand so you don't need to write the full `Pattern` and for when you have one symbol but a complex pattern object on the rhs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is useful when your pattern does not start with `_`.  Suppose your pattern is a list of integers,

```
total[list : {__Integer}] := Total[list]
total[___] := $Failed
```

Or a variable that can be true or false:

```
func[arg:(True | False)] := If[arg, foo, bar]
func[___] := $Failed
```

Comment: I m sorry but i don t understand your first explanation. Can you develop a bit more ?

Answer (score 0):

A colon is useful to name a filter with the following syntax: `name:filter`. For example, `polarPlot[r_, domain:{t_, tmin_, tmax_}]:=ParametricPlot[{r Cost[t], r Sin[t]}, domain]` domain specifies a list of 3 éléments.

It can be useful also to factor a filter as `r_Integer|r_Rational` in `r:(_Integer,_Rational)`